# How to solve recurrences of the form $T(i,n) = \min_{x} f(x) + \max\{T(i,x),T(x,n)\}$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I am interested in solving a recurrence of the form:

$$T(i,n) = \begin{cases}\min_{x\in\{i+1,\ldots,n-1\}} f(x) + \max\{T(i,x),T(x,n)\} & \mbox{If $i<n-1$}\\ 1 & \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}\quad.$$

This arises from an application where we perform a nested binary search for $k$ variables $v_1\le v_2\le\cdots\le v_k$, where we check the derivative of our cost function with respect to the $v_k$, what costs time $f(x)$.
The point is that there's asymmetry between how long it'll take to complete the execution if the optimal value of $v_k$ is larger than $x$ (at which point we just learn that $v_k\ge x$) or when $v_k\le x$ (where we immediately learn that $v_1, v_2,\ldots, v_{k-1}$ are also bounded by $x$).

To make this more concrete, let's take an example of $f(x) = \log_2 x$, so we get the recurrence:
$$T_2(i,n) = \begin{cases}\min_{x\in\{i+1,\ldots,n-1\}} \log_2 x + \max\{T(i,x),T(x,n)\} & \mbox{If $i<n-1$}\\ 1 & \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}\quad.$$

> **Is $T_2(1,n) = \Theta(\log^2 n)$ or $T_2(1,n)=o(\log^2 n)$?**

A bound of $T_2=O(\log^2 n)$ is given by picking $x=\frac{i+n}{2}$ each time, which corresponds to a standard binary search.

I wrote a simple script that finds the optimal $x$ value for a given $i,n$, and it seems to confirm that $x=\frac{i+n}{2}$ is not ideal (e.g., for $i=1, n=500$, the best choice of $x$ is $372$).

> **More generally, how to approach recurrences such as $T(i,n)$?**

Ideally, I'd like to understand the asymptotic behavior of $T(1,n)$ and how to calculate $x$ efficiently.

Comment: The recurrence for $T(i, n)$ you stated is very similar to the recurrence for computing the optimal product of matrices, i.e. a parenthesization of the product of matrices such that computing the product requires the fewest number of operations, which is: $$T(i, n) = \min_{k \in {i + 1, ... , n - 1  }} (1 + T(i, k) + T(k + 1, n)) $$ and whose time complexity is $\Omega (n^3)$ using dynamic programming.

Comment: @prcssngnr -- thanks for the pointer! I think the problem becomes somewhat harder when $f$ is not constant.

Comment: The dynamic programming solution to the recurrence with $O(1)$ additional work is $\Theta (n^3)$. In your recurrence when taking into consideration that each reference to $T(i, n)$ also does $O(\lg n)$ additional work we may conclude something like $T(1, n) = O(n^3 \lg n)$ or $T(1, n) = \omega(n^3)$.

Comment: @prcssngnr -- thanks, but I don't think that this is correct. Note that your DP sums up $T(i,k)$ and $T(k+1,n)$, while mine has $\max\{T(i,x), T(x,n)\}$. 
My $T_2$ function is clearly satisfies $T_2(1,n)=O(\log^2 n)$ which is obtained by taking $x=(i+n)/2$ each time.

Comment: For each call of $T(i, n)$ you call all $T(i, k)$ and $T(k + 1, i)$ with $k \in i + 1, ... n - 1$ and take the minimum. You are still making all those calls.

Comment: Correction: For each call of $T(i, n)$ you call all $T(i, k)$ and $T(k + 1, n)$ with $k \in i + 1, ..., n - 1$. Also, note that the cost of your recurrence relation: $$ T(i, n) = \min_{k \in i + 1, ..., n - 1} \lg k + \max \left(T(i, k), T(k + 1, j) \right)$$ is: $$ T(i, n) = \sum_{k = i + 1}^{n - 1} \lg k + T(i, k) + T(k + 1, n)$$

Comment: @M A It may be that the recurrence you stated does not accurately represent the computation you are trying to perform. If this is the case you should probably edit the recurrence in the question. As it is now you will not be getting better than $\omega (n^3)$.

Comment: Maybe you meant that $T(i, n) = \lg \left( \frac{i + n}{2}  \right) + T\left( i, \frac{i + n}{2} \right) +  T\left( \frac{i + n}{2} + 1, n \right)$ which can be modelled as $T(n) = 2T\left( \frac{n}{2} \right) + \lg \frac{n}{2}$ in which case we conclude $T(n) = \Theta(n)$. Though maybe you meant something else. For me it's not very clear what you would like to compute.

Comment: @prcssngnr -- no, I meant exactly the recurrence in the question. This $T$ models the runtime of an algorithm. I can *choose* which $x$ to check, which costs $f(x)$ time, and depending on the outcome, I may have to recurse to *either* $(i,x)$ *or* $(x,n)$. I'm looking at the worst-case, which is why I get the $\max\{\cdot\}$.
Solving this recurrence would allow me to optimize the choice of $x$ and accelerate the algorithm. In any case, I'm trying to solve the recurrence in the question, not compute anything :).

Comment: @prcssngnr - P.S. I'm not sure what you mean by `the cost of your recurrence relation'. I am not asking about the computational complexity of solving it but rather if there's an analytical way to solve it.

Comment: @M A In the current form of the recurrence relation you search all $x$ with $x \in i + 1, ..., n - 1$ from which you conclude that $T(n) = \omega(n^3)$ using dynamic programming. You mention that you are looking for some $x$ and depending on some outcome you recurse either down one path or another. The current form of your recurrence does not capture this decision using the notation you did. And on the basis of what outcome do you decide this $x$? And there are several ways to solve recurrences. For example using the substitution method, generating functions or expanding the recurrence.

Comment: @M A On the basis of your comments where you choose $x$ which costs $f(x)$ we get the recurrence $T(i, n) = f(x) +  \max \left( T(i, x), T(x, n) \right)$ where by $\max$ I mean the decision either $T(i, x)$ or $T(x + 1, n)$ you mentioned, which can modelled more simply as $T(n) = f(x) + T\left( \frac{n}{2}  \right)$. Taking $f(x) = \lg x$ and $x = n / 2$ we get $T(n) = \Theta(\lg{n}^2)$. I used the expansion method for solving recurrences to arrive at the bound.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that when using dynamic programming when solving the first recurrence you stated (interpreted in the usual way one does when such notation is used, see Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et al.), the efficiency of the algorithm is determined by the number of subproblems and the number of operations performed in each subproblem. However, when not using dynamic programming then the bound of the first recurrence you stated is exponential. Such recurrences can be solved using the methods I mentioned, e.g. the substitution method etc.

Comment: @prcssngnr - but your analysis avoids taking the minimum over $x$. By plugging in $x=(i+n)/2$ we can upper bound $T(i,n)$, but not get a tight bound. As I explained in the question, the value of $x$ that minimizes $T$ is different.

Comment: @M A If you have to vary the range of $x$ between $i + 1$ and $n - 1$ and recurse either $(i, x)$ or $(x + 1, n)$ then according to the recurrence you provided you get something like $T(n) = O(n^2 \lg n)$ or $T(n) = \omega(n^2)$.

Comment: @prcssngnr -- you are again talking about the time it takes to calculate $T(n)$ and not the value of $T(i,n)$ itself. I am not talking about the computational aspects at all in this question.

Comment: @M A Then I feel I should say it's a bit confusing if you ask questions like: "Is this $\Theta(\log^2{n})$" or that you want to understand the "asymptotic behaviour of $T(1, n)$" which are precisely about time complexity. Also: "you are again talking about the time it takes to calculate $T(n)$ and not the value of $T(i, n)$ itself": Are you implying that you want the value of $T(i, n)$ itself? In that case, then expand the recurrence to perhaps get a closed form for $T$, if you're lucky or otherwise you can always write a program to compute it and do some experiments.

Comment: @prcssngnr - I am losing you here. Asymptotics of recurrence relations (or in general, functions) has nothing to do with computation and existed long before time complexity was studied. As mentioned in the question, I did write a program that computes $T(i,n)$, and it indicated that one can do better than choosing $x=(i+n)/2$. That is, the $T(i,n) < f((i+n)/2) + \max\{T(i,(i+n)/2),T((i+n)/2,n)\}$ for most reasonable $f$s, including $f(x)=\log x$.
Nothing in the question (or comments) suggests interest in the time complexity of computing $T$.

Comment: @M A Yes it appears so. Can you briefly state the steps of the algorithm or provide some pseudocode (you said this came from an application)? Also, if you like you can increase exposure of this question by modifying it, e.g. adding a new tag, thereby putting it at the top of the questions list and maybe that way someone else will take a look at the question that can help better than I can.

Comment: Note: In my previous comment by algorithm I mean $T$.

Comment: Also: See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) for a description of what time complexity is. Time complexity is about the asymptotic behaviour of an algorithm.